# How to logout or End a user session using Twitter Api?

Tags: objective-c, twitter

I am developing an iPhone application which will excess multiple user account, but when i add a new user, i save it's Request token information and access token information. And for a new user I need to end the session to store the new user's information. For that I am trying to call the API mentioned below but it's not ending the session and giving me following error message:

API : "http://api.twitter.com/1/account/end_session.xml"

Error Message: "Error Domain=HTTP Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.)"

What i am doing wrong ? Kindly give me some advice.

Comment: can you edit your question to show a little bit of code that demonstrates *how* you are calling the `end_session` API?

Comment: I wonder what could be the reason to down vote this question? Who ever did so, will you kindly explain?

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete your access token.

Comment: i did delete the token, but the next time it opens the dialog and doesn't ask for the username and password, it just asks me to authorize the app. Moreover if i try to unset the twitter engine object, the next time it gives me error that the token is invalid.